# JS Light bulb switch on/off on daytime

Tags: javascript

I am getting into javascript and recently bumped into if statements. My isssue is that lightbulb should be either switched on/off based on time of the day. So if the time is equal or greater than 10 and equal or lesser than 15.00, it going to be on, else its gonig to be off. For some odd reason it won't switch from the off one. Here is mycode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="myImage" onload="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<script>
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
var hour = now.getHours();
function changeImage() {
if (hour >= 10 && <= 15) {
image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
} 
else {
image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try create a Date instance, like: var d = Date(); var n = d.getHours(); and check a "n" variable in your if conditional.

Comment: Where is `now` defined? You seem to have an undefined variable, which your F12 Debugger should be informing you of.

Comment: Check my pen based in your case: https://codepen.io/edsonfilho10/pen/povQQRd open the console and change a "hour" value inside if conditional to check changes

Comment: correction: var d = `new` Date(); var n = d.getHours();

Answer (score 2):

So you did a few things wrong:

1. If you want to use date, you first need to declare a `var` with the value of `new Date`. You can learn more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
2. your `if` statement had two faults

   fault 1: `(hour >= 10 && <= 15)` after `&&` you forgot to set the value 15 needs to be langer then. correct way would have been `(hour >= 10 && hour <= 15)`

   fault 2: is that if you use `&&` it means both conditions must be true. Which is not what you want. You want to use `||` which means or. Either `hour >= 10` is true or `hour >= 15`
3. Also you need to execute your function or it won't work, and onload on an img as the way you are using it won't work. You can however run it by placing `changeImage();` underneath your `func`.

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();

function changeImage() {
if (hour >= 10 || hour <= 15) {

image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
} 
else {

image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";

}
}

changeImage();
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmrbse0f/)

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the code a bit, now it works as intended. I had to use && because the condition is set to time between 8 and 14 (8,9,10,11,12,13,14) - on these hours bulb will be off, else it will be on.

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
var hour = new Date();
hour = hour.getHours();

function changeImage() {
if (hour >=8 && hour <= 14 ) {
image.src = "http://blogdecorwatts.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tipos-del%C3%A2mpadas-incandescentes.jpg";
} else {
image.src = "https://www.educolorir.com/imagem-lampada-ligada-dm26249.jpg";
}
}
```